# Measure Installs via Google Chrome Native App Install Banner

Tags: android, google-chrome, native

I have a question about the [Native App Install Banner](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/app-install-banners/#native_app_install_banners) in Google Chrome on Android. I added the snippet to my manifest.json and the banner is working fine.

Now I wonder: Is there a way to find out how many people are installing my android app through this banner?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Have you found an answer?

Comment: I'm afraid not.